# Is there any XAML Grid element equivalent in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, wpf, xaml

I have a deep experience about WPF, XAML, etc. However, I'd need to create something in HTML/CSS/JS.

In WPF, but also in Silverlight, there is a very versatile element which is the "Grid". It's essentially a list hosting any kind of visual object, which will be arranged accordingly to the row/column collection definitions.

Here is a (simple IMHO) example for the non-xaml addicted:

http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

I believe it's the most important control for managing the layout of the visual.

Now, I'm wondering whether is there any equivalent "component" for the web world, possibly simple and clean: not tons of code for such a simple problem. In other words, I don't want to rely on frameworks such as ASP.Net, ExtJS or else. Just a guideline, with a minimal HTML/CSS/JS section.

It's fine relying on the most recent browsers.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What about css grid systems like bootstrap or foundation? take a look http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html or http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.php

Comment: Thanks, Michele. I've already seen the Zurb-way, but it's much like a patch over a pretty common problem. However, it's "common" IMHO, but maybe it isn't so for the majority!
Moreover, you can't span over rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one by myself, although it's still under development: at the moment seems that only IE10 implements it.

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_grid.htm

I really hope this feature won't be trashed in a short.

Comment: Well, AFAIK it's not MS exclusive, but a W3C recommendation. I've seen on the Chrome-side and it seems they're started the implementation, but...it'll be successful?

Comment: Well, the notation starting with '-ms' seemed to imply otherwise. A better page regarding the matter would probably be [the one on w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/) (wow, just noticed the date: 8 May 2013). Also i sure hope something like this get universal support, the lack of a decent grid layout is infuriating if you want to have dynamic rows in an application-type website.

Comment: update from 2020: CSS grid is fantastic, and is even better than WPF's grid in some ways. it's well-supported.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I agree, but it has still some problems on Mac: both Safari and Chrome. For this reason, at the moment I prefer to use flex than grid.