# Is there any similar control in asp.net like Wpf Grid

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf

Recently I moved to `Asp.net` from `WPF` and I am missing `Wpf Grid` in asp.net. 
I am using `table` to get the same UI in asp.net but this is nothing in comparison to wpf Grid. 
 Is there any way to use Grid in Asp? 
or any other similar control exist?
 Note : `GridView` is not my thing.
**Edit:** I am interested in Layout control, not in tabular data display control.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460343/is-there-any-xaml-grid-element-equivalent-in-html-css

Comment: No proper answer in ur link :(

Comment: I never claimed otherwise.

Comment: According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx), the `TableLayoutPanel` is the Winforms equivalent of the WPF's `Grid`. I'm not sure if that's available in ASP.Net though.

Comment: GridView is the standard "out of the box" control - other than that I could suggest jQuery DataTables http://www.datatables.net/ - this is client side (with ajax) solution that is often used when GridView is not enough.

Comment: What's wrong with `GridView`? ASP.NET will always be limited by the fact it has to output HTML, so tables are your main choice either output by .NET controls or coded directly - You can always prettify them with DataTables.net as said or something like jqGrid.

Comment: Have you tried Silverlight?

Comment: Maybe the question needs to be more precise because there are confusion in the comments.

Are you interested in WPF Grid (what you said), which is a layout control (a WPF Panel) -- or in a datagrid to display tabular data (you mention ASP.NET GridView)?

Comment: for table haters : u can do the same things with  learning doing html/css layouts  . if you want fast way then use bootstrap layouts .http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

Comment: Did you try ListViewControl?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt you will find any true ASP.NET control that present the layout options you have in WPF Grid like auto-sized columns and such.

What I would probably choose if faced with the same requirement is to go with client side scripting for layout: there is jQuery plugin called [Masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) and it appears its [multi-column example](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-multi-column.html) fits your need.

Each "table cell" is actually a `<div>` element and you specify the column as part of its class e.g. `box col1 masonry-brick` then the jQuery plugin organize them all together.

Less elegant than Grid, but it gives you good control over the layout.